# Buffer Overflow does not work on Mac OSX El Capitan

Tags: c, macos, osx-elcapitan, buffer-overflow

I've bought Jon Erickson's book "Hacking - The Art of Exploitation" and in it he describes a simple example of a buffer overflow like so:

```
int check_authentication(char *password) {
    int auth_flag = 0;
    char password_buffer[16];

    strcpy(password_buffer, password);

    if(strcmp(password_buffer, "password") == 0)
        auth_flag = 1;

    return auth_flag
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if(argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s <password>\n", argv[0]);
    }

    if(check_authentication(argv[1])) {
        printf("Access Granted.\n");
    } else {
        printf("Access Denied.\n");
    }
}
```

After compiling at first I tested with `./a.out password`, which obviously works, then with `./a.out testtest`, which also works as expected. However if I want to invoke a buffer overflow via entering `./a.out AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA` (which are exactly 17 'A's, thus one too many for the `password_buffer`) to get the program to misbehave and print `Access Granted.`, the program just quits and the OSX El Capitan tells me I've got a `segmentation fault`. (Btw. I've also tried with more 'A's, but obviously still got the same error.)

Why is this? Is Apple's Memory Management too evolved to be tricked by simple things like this? Help would be greatly appreciated! If you know other good sites that explain how hacking can be learned, feel free to reference them!

Comment: likely the operating system is employing some more advanced [buffer overflow protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow_protection) techniques

Comment: Just sit back and think about the implications of **undefined** behaviour.

Comment: Do you know a way to turn that off? I've skimmed through the article and tried things like `gcc -fno-stack-protector`, but now the program just aborts directly

Comment: @Olaf haha I'd love to! But thinking about it just does not seem enough, I want to **see** it happening!

Comment: @lindebear: If you had, you would have noticed that you actually **did** see it happen.

Comment: Your compiler may be optimizing auth_flag away, since you just return 0 or 1 from it. So that only leaves the return address after the password buffer, and you get a segfault.

Comment: So do something with auth_flag to trick the compiler.

Comment: @olaf: Well in the sense of my program aborting, I did see it haha

Comment: @ctrl-d: I'm looking into that as we speak! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ctrl-d: I tried things like declaring the variable as `volatile` or even declaring it globally as `static` reading it within the `main()` after calling `check_authentication()`... however that does not seem to change anything, have you got any pro-tips?

Comment: Maybe try using it in an external function: auth_flag = dup(auth_flag); auth_flag = 0;

Comment: @ctrl-d: I found the solution! Wasn't due to the compiler optimizing away my variables, just gcc being overly cautious by default. Thanks a lot for your help though! :D

Comment: Now try to craft something that gets you a shell prompt with this overflow. :]

Comment: @ctrl-d: Right away! haha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just found the solution! (yay \o/)

At first I tried compiling it via:
`gcc -fno-stack-protector auth_overflow.c`

However that didn't help much. I had to also set the `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0`-flag to zero, like so:
`gcc -fno-stack-protector -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 auth_overflow.c`.

This way it finally worked and I got:

```
./a.out AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
Access Granted.
```